# how to google for help about 'scientific linux' related questions?

Tags: scientific-linux

I tried googling for help on several questions related to the scientific linux distribution.

Similar distributions have somewhat non-colliding handles ( "RHEL", "CentOS", ..) that are very good search engine "filters".

Is there an effective, standard way to search for "scientific linux" pages that i maybe missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scientific Linux is based on RHEL. Thus, all the documentation and Google results available for it (and for CentOS, too) may help you.

If you need distro-specific info, try to get help from Scientific Linux mailing lists: https://www.scientificlinux.org/maillists/, particularly from the first one - Scientific-Linux-Users.

Comment: ok so RHEL and CentOS would be the keywords then. Thanks.